# MySql Query - Expanding data into new table

Tags: mysql

I have data stored in a MySQL table and need to extract it and store it into a new table in a very specific way:

The data is in a customer table for example:

```
ID String | Region Identifier
abcdefg   | 123456
bcdefgh   | 123456
cdefghi   | 123456
defghij   | 456789
efghijk   | 456789
fghijkl   | 456789
```

I want to be able to show all the combinations of ID Strings under a certain region identifier (where there are more than one id strings in that region) and store this in another table. For example the above data will end up in another table such as:

```
ID Strings                 | Region Identifier | Count
abcdefg, bcdefgh, cdefghi  | 123456            |  3
abcdefg, cdefghi           | 123456            |  2
abcdefg, bcdefgh           | 123456            |  2
bcdefgh, cdefghi           | 123456            |  2
defghij, efghijk, fghijkl  | 456789            |  3
defghij, fghijkl           | 456789            |  2
defghij, efghijk           | 456789            |  2
efghijk, fghijkl           | 456789            |  2
```

I also want to ensure the ID Strings (which can be a combination of number and letters) appear in alphabetical order (within the ID String Field) and will need to convert them into an integer based on the string. So for example (abcdefg, bcdefgh, cdefghi) will become 2454574579. (i need to be able to get this ID whenever these 3 exact strings are combined).

I would prefer to do this is raw SQL if possible but if not i'm happy to use python, php, javascript but whatever is quickest.

Comment: In which basis (abcdefg, bcdefgh, cdefghi) will become 2454574579 ?

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon it needs to get the numerical equivalent of those characters. The example was quite bad though as i should have used the real ascii numerical equivalent in my example. So the actual value of "abcdefg, bcdefgh, cdefghi" would be 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 44 32 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 44 32 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 however that is a bit long so if there is a better way i'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want the total number of combinations, which can be infinite depending on the number of unique Ids per region. If you have X unique IDs, you need to make X number of self joins. 
Every Join without a where condition, can produce another combination for you.

So you need to use a stored procedure.

The first step though, would be to do a group_concat.
I would also make use of the following stored procedure: https://gist.github.com/avoidwork/3749973

You use group concat:

```
create table testing(
  idString varchar(20),
  region varchar(20)
);

insert into testing values("abcdefg","123456");
insert into testing values("bcdefgh","123456");
insert into testing values("cdefghi","123456");
insert into testing values("defghij","456789");
insert into testing values("efghijk","456789");
insert into testing values("fghijkl","456789");


select region, group_concat(idString) from testing group by region;
```

What is remaining and I will post later on, is to do a conversion to numerical euivalent of character using ascii value. And to also do an order by.

### Update

Change the code as required.
Please note the below gets all combinations in all orders of IDString.

```
        #Init Stuff

#Will not work without the following command/Setting:
SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_split`;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getCombinations`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp` (
  `col` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `result` (
  `idStrings` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `region` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `count` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

delete from result;
delete from temp;

create view  IF NOT EXISTS groupByBugWorkaroundView as select   region as region, count(distinct idString) as countInt, group_concat(idString) as csv from testing group by region;

delimiter ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_split`(IN toSplit text, IN target char(255))
  BEGIN
    # Temp table variables
    SET @tableName = 'tmpSplit';
    SET @fieldName = 'variable';

    #select toSplit;

    # Dropping table
    SET @sql := CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', @tableName);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


    # Creating table
    SET @sql := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', @tableName, ' (', @fieldName, ' VARCHAR(1000))');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


    # Preparing toSplit
    SET @vars := toSplit;
    SET @vars := CONCAT("('", REPLACE(@vars, ",", "'),('"), "')");

    delete from tmpSplit;

    # Inserting values
    SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @tableName, ' VALUES ', @vars);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    # Returning record set, or inserting into optional target
    IF target IS NULL THEN
      SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT TRIM(`', @fieldName, '`) AS `', @fieldName, '` FROM ', @tableName);
    ELSE
      SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', target, ' SELECT TRIM(`', @fieldName, '`) FROM ', @tableName);
    END IF;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  END
;;

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE PROCEDURE getCombinations()
  BEGIN

    DECLARE countInt INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE csv varchar(100);
    DECLARE region varchar(100);
    DECLARE v_last_row_fetched INT;
    declare v_counter int unsigned default 1;

    DECLARE counter cursor for select  * from groupByBugWorkaroundView;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET  v_last_row_fetched=1;

    SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');

    delete from result;
    delete from tmpSplit;
    COMMIT;

    open counter;
    c1_loop: loop
      fetch counter into region , countInt, csv ;

      IF  v_last_row_fetched=1 THEN LEAVE c1_loop; END IF;

      CALL sp_split(csv, null);

      #       delete from temp;
      #       insert into temp select * from tempSplit;
      #       commit;

      set @q0 = concat('insert into result select t0.variable ');
      set @q1 = concat(' from tmpSplit t0');
      set @q3 = concat(' where 1=1 ');
      set @q4 = ',\''  || region || ' \'' ;

      #-- DEBUG
      #       set @tempLog = concat('insert into templog values (\'',@q1);
      #       set @tempLog = concat(@q1, ' '');');
      #       PREPARE stmt1 FROM @tempLog;
      #       EXECUTE stmt1;
      #       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
      #-- END DEBUG

      set v_counter = 1;
      while v_counter < countInt do

        set @q1 := concat(@q1,  ' ,tmpSplit t');
        set @q1 := concat(@q1 ,  v_counter);

        set @q0 := concat(@q0, '|| \',\' || t');
        set @q0 := concat(@q0, v_counter);
        set @q0 := concat(@q0, '.variable');

        #Necessary joins
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, ' AND not t');
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, v_counter-1);
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, '.variable = ');
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, ' t');
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, v_counter);
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, '.variable ');

        #Alphabetical order
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, ' AND not t');
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, v_counter-1);
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, '.variable > ');
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, ' t');
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, v_counter);
        set @q3 := concat(@q3, '.variable ');

        set v_counter=v_counter+1;

        set @q5 = ',\''  || v_counter || '\'' ;

        set @q9 := concat('', '');
        set @q9 := concat( @q0, @q4);
        set @q9 := concat( @q9, @q5);
        set @q9 := concat( @q9, @q1);
        set @q9 := concat( @q9, @q3);
        select @q9 as debug;

        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @q9;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
        commit;

      end while;

      delete from temp; commit;

    end loop c1_loop;
    close counter;

  END;

DELIMITER ;

CALL getCombinations();
select distinct idStrings, region, count from result order by region, count  desc;
```

### DB Fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mHyWsoRjoQwESHtuLiFQ2y/0

### Optimized Updates

This version replaces the multiple insert statements into only one insert statement:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mHyWsoRjoQwESHtuLiFQ2y/0

```
#Will not work without the following command/Setting:
SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');


create table IF NOT EXISTS testing(
  idString varchar(20),
  region varchar(20)
);

delete from testing;

insert into testing values("abcdefg","123456");
insert into testing values("bcdefgh","123456");
insert into testing values("cdefghi","123456");
insert into testing values("defghij","456789");
insert into testing values("efghijk","456789");
insert into testing values("fghijkl","456789");


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_split`;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getCombinations`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp` (
  `col` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
  ENGINE = MEMORY;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmpSplit` (
  `variable` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
  ENGINE = MEMORY;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `result` (
  `idStrings` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `region`    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `count`     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
  ENGINE = MEMORY;

DELETE FROM result;
DELETE FROM temp;


DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `testingWithBlanks`;
CREATE VIEW testingWithBlanks AS
  SELECT
    idString,
    region
  FROM testing
  UNION
  select  distinct ' ' as idString , region from testing;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `groupByBugWorkaroundView`;
CREATE VIEW groupByBugWorkaroundView AS
  SELECT
    region                   AS region,
    count(DISTINCT idString) AS countInt,
    group_concat(idString)   AS csv
  FROM testingWithBlanks
  GROUP BY region;

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_split`(IN toSplit TEXT, IN target CHAR(255))
  BEGIN
    # Temp table variables
    SET @tableName = 'tmpSplit';
    SET @fieldName = 'variable';

    #select toSplit;

    # Dropping table
    SET @sql := CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', @tableName);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    # Creating table
    SET @sql := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', @tableName, ' (', @fieldName, ' VARCHAR(1000))');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    # Preparing toSplit
    SET @vars := toSplit;
    SET @vars := CONCAT("('", REPLACE(@vars, ",", "'),('"), "')");

    DELETE FROM tmpSplit;

    # Inserting values
    SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @tableName, ' VALUES ', @vars);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    # Returning record set, or inserting into optional target
    IF target IS NULL
    THEN
      SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT TRIM(`', @fieldName, '`) AS `', @fieldName, '` FROM ', @tableName);
    ELSE
      SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', target, ' SELECT TRIM(`', @fieldName, '`) FROM ', @tableName);
    END IF;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  END;


DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `subStringCount`;
CREATE FUNCTION `subStringCount`(sequence VARCHAR(1000), word VARCHAR(100))
  RETURNS INT(4)
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
  BEGIN
    DECLARE counter SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE word_length SMALLINT UNSIGNED;

    SET word_length = CHAR_LENGTH(word);

    WHILE (INSTR(sequence, word) != 0) DO
      SET counter = counter + 1;
      SET sequence = SUBSTR(sequence, INSTR(sequence, word) + word_length);
    END WHILE;

    RETURN counter;
  END;


CREATE PROCEDURE getCombinations()
  BEGIN

    DECLARE countInt INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE csv VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE region2 VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_last_row_fetched INT;
    DECLARE v_counter INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;

    DECLARE counter CURSOR FOR SELECT *
                               FROM groupByBugWorkaroundView;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_last_row_fetched = 1;

    SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');

    DELETE FROM result;
    DELETE FROM tmpSplit;
    COMMIT;

    OPEN counter;
    c1_loop: LOOP
      FETCH counter
      INTO region2, countInt, csv;

      IF v_last_row_fetched = 1
      THEN LEAVE c1_loop;
      END IF;

      CALL sp_split(csv, NULL);

      #       delete from temp;
      #       insert into temp select * from tempSplit;
      #       commit;

      SET @q0 = concat('insert into result select t0.variable ');
      SET @q1 = concat(' from tmpSplit t0');
      SET @q3 = concat(' where 1=1 ');
      SET @q4 = ',\'' || region2 || ' \'';

      #-- DEBUG
      #       set @tempLog = concat('insert into templog values (\'',@q1);
      #       set @tempLog = concat(@q1, ' '');');
      #       PREPARE stmt1 FROM @tempLog;
      #       EXECUTE stmt1;
      #       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
      #-- END DEBUG

      SET v_counter = 1;
      WHILE v_counter < countInt DO

        SET @q1 := concat(@q1, ' ,tmpSplit t');
        SET @q1 := concat(@q1, v_counter);

        SET @q0 := concat(@q0, '|| \',\' || t');
        SET @q0 := concat(@q0, v_counter);
        SET @q0 := concat(@q0, '.variable');

        #Necessary joins
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, ' AND (not t');
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, v_counter - 1);
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, '.variable = ');
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, ' t');
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, v_counter);
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, '.variable ');

        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, ' OR t');
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, v_counter - 1);
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, '.variable = ');
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, '\' \')  ');

        #Alphabetical order
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, ' AND not t');
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, v_counter - 1);
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, '.variable > ');
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, ' t');
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, v_counter);
        SET @q3 := concat(@q3, '.variable ');

        SET v_counter = v_counter + 1;

        SET @q5 = ',\'' || v_counter || '\'';

        SET @q9 := concat('', '');
        SET @q9 := concat(@q0, @q4);
        SET @q9 := concat(@q9, @q5);
        SET @q9 := concat(@q9, @q1);
        SET @q9 := concat(@q9, @q3);


      END WHILE;

      SELECT @q9 AS debug;

      PREPARE stmt1 FROM @q9;
      EXECUTE stmt1;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
      COMMIT;

      DELETE FROM temp;
      COMMIT;

    END LOOP c1_loop;
    CLOSE counter;

  END;


CALL getCombinations();

SELECT
  idStrings,
  region,
  subStringCount(idStrings, ',') + 1 AS count
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      REPLACE(idStrings, ' ,', '') AS idStrings,
      region
    FROM result
  ) temp
WHERE subStringCount(idStrings, ',') > 0
ORDER BY region, subStringCount(idStrings, ',') + 1 DESC;
```

### Update

With comments about what people could improve (as todo's):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJ2XuB893is9ENaXxuFgCZ/0

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You are very close to what I am after however I only want the combinations under that region so region 123456 has 3 unique ID_Strings which means there are 4 possible combinations of those 3 ID's (as long as each combination uses 2 or more ids). I am also interested how to do the char to ascii number conversion so that would be great if you could post that. Thanks.

Comment: @SamBremner Added a new answer that is a stored procedure and gives you what you need. You just need to add the numerical conversion which isn't anything special.

Comment: @SamBremner Ping

Comment: Very detailed answer that does exactly what i wanted. Thanks Menelaos