# Remove older logs than 2 months from all tables starting with raw_%

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I got mysql database which contains tables with logs from other systems. Each system has its own table, I want to automatically remove logs older than 2 months. I almost got it but I get an error during PREPARING the statement.

This is what I got:

```
-- Set up variable to delete ALL tables starting with 'raw_'
SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=100000;

SET @delStmt = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('DELETE FROM `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, '` WHERE time < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH);') SEPARATOR ' ')
       FROM information_schema.TABLES
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'log_cmd'
        AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'raw_%');

-- SELECT @delStmt;

PREPARE stmt FROM @delStmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

And the error I get is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM `log_cmd`.`raw_10203040` WHERE time < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)' at line 1
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### How to debug

You should un comment `-- SELECT @delStmt;` , and comment the last three lines.
You will get back the actual generated SQL statement.

You can then copy and run the statement on the actual server to get the real error message.

### Observations

I ran your statement on my own system and I get null.

However, I don't have the same tables on my system, so I removed the where condition in `delStmt` and am getting the following:

> DELETE FROM `information_schema`.`ALL_PLUGINS` WHERE time < DATE(NOW()
>   - INTERVAL 2 MONTH); DELETE FROM `information_schema`.`APPLICABLE_ROLES` WHERE time < DATE(NOW() -
>   INTERVAL 2 MONTH); DELETE FROM `information_schema`.`CHARACTER_SETS`
>   WHERE time < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH); DELETE FROM
>   `information_schema`.`COLLATIONS` WHERE time < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2
>   MONTH); ...

And the list goes on ...

### Update

I think the error is actually related to trying to execute two SQL statements, separated by a `;`.

I was able to successfully execute the delete statements one by one.

**Proof of concept:**

```
drop table raw_1;
create table raw_1(
  time int
);

drop table raw_2;
create table raw_2(
  time int
);

SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=100000;

SET @delStmt = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('DELETE FROM `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, '` WHERE time < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH);') SEPARATOR ' ')
                FROM information_schema.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'raw_%');

SELECT @delStmt;

PREPARE stmt FROM @delStmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Result:**

```
DELETE FROM `test`.`raw_1` WHERE time < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH); \
DELETE FROM `test`.`raw_2` WHERE time < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH);
```

### Final Answer

The command was failing due to being multiple statements. Splitting the execution into multiple solves the problem. Another solution is to save the commands to a file and execute (as Alek says).

```
#Will not work without the following command/Setting:
SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');

drop table raw_1;
create table  IF NOT EXISTS  raw_1(
  time int
);

create table  IF NOT EXISTS  raw_2(
  time int
);

SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `deleteFromLogs`;

CREATE PROCEDURE deleteFromLogs()
  BEGIN

    DECLARE torun varchar(100);
    DECLARE v_last_row_fetched INT;
    DECLARE counter CURSOR FOR SELECT 'DELETE FROM `' || TABLE_SCHEMA || '`.`' || TABLE_NAME || '` WHERE time < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH);' as torun
                               FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'raw_%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'log_cmd' ;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_last_row_fetched = 1;

    SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');

    OPEN counter;
    c1_loop: LOOP
      FETCH counter
      INTO torun;

      IF v_last_row_fetched = 1
      THEN LEAVE c1_loop;
      END IF;

      SET @delStmt = torun;
      select @delStmt;

#       PREPARE stmt1 FROM @delStmt;
#       EXECUTE stmt1;
#       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
#       COMMIT;

    END LOOP c1_loop;
    CLOSE counter;

  END;


CALL deleteFromLogs();
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cVJ4uDhQYQALMvSURSEq4Y/1

Comment: Tried it. I get whole statement which works, I mean I can copy it and run it without any errors, and it does what I want(so deletes records from raw_% tables).
Any ideas how to deal with more than 1 statement in prepare?

Comment: @Alek I think you need to execute the statements one by one... instead of trying all of them together.

Comment: Any idea how to execute statement one by one?

Comment: @Alek , one way to do it would be to rewrite the code to do a query, and then have a loop with a `fetch into` and run one delete statement per loop. I have a previous answer where I used a loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46828262/mysql-query-expanding-data-into-new-table/46829411#46829411 . However, it would probably be easier for you if you find a stored procedure to split your statement by `;` and do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. The easiest way is to put commands into a file and execute it.

```
SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=100000;

SET @delStmt = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('DELETE FROM `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, '` WHERE time < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH);') SEPARATOR ' ')
   FROM information_schema.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'log_cmd'
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'raw_%');

SELECT @delStmt INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/temp.sql';
SOURCE /tmp/temp.sql;
```

Thanks for help

Comment: @Ofcourse, this required read/write privileges and also if the file already exists, an error is generated`` 'emp.sql' already exists.